# How to stop $_session message appearing?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

this is my delete page for a project. I would like to be able to only allow the specific logged in user to delete only their record /account.

So i have a table of the user info, and a link to this `delete.php` page. The following code allows them to delete their own record, but displays the `$_session['delete']` message, even though it does not allow them to delete an other's record.

Can anyone advise?

Thanks.

```
<?php


 include 'dbconnect.php';

session_start();

// CHECK IF LOGGED IN //

if( ! $_SESSION['username'] ) {

header("Location: project-users-logout.php");
die();
}

// Build SQL Query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registeredUsers";

// Run the Query
$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['id']); 

$deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM registeredUsers 
                WHERE UserID = $userid
                AND UserName = '$_SESSION[username]'";

$delete = mysqli_query($db, $deleteQuery);  

if ($delete) { 

             /* SUCCESS */ 
            $_SESSION['delete'] = 'Record deleted';
             header ("Location: project-users-manage.php ");
             exit;

} else {

    echo "You do not have access to delete this user";
}
```

?>

Comment: Look into using `mysqli_affected_rows()` on your check if something was actually deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe $delete evaluates to true because the statement always executes successfully, even if the user wasn't deleted because the delete-query didn't find anything to delete.

I would personally:

- First, check if they're logged in at all, as you're doing
- Second, check security based on the id/session by pulling the user's row with a SELECT, and checking that it exists/permissions/etc.
- Third, if the user has permission, delete the row and set a variable $bDeleted=true ... else don't delete the row and set $bDeleted=false
- Fourth, echo based on $bDeleted

Also, I would not delete a user's row. It's more safe to mark the row as deleted with a boolean field in the database, and adjust your app's logic to simply regard such rows as deleted. That way you can quickly un-delete user accounts in case of accidents or changes of heart.

Comment: I'm sorry... i have missed the task. It is actually to stop the user deleting themselves. So the logged in user can delete everyone, except themselves. Any idea how i would go about that?